# include_path error when invoking Zend Framework 2 commandline tool

Tags: php, zend-framework2, include-path

When attempting to run 'create project' in Zend from command line using zf I get the following error:

> In order to run the zf command, you need to ensure that Zend Framework
>   is inside your include_path

I'm using XAMPP and my php ini located at: C:\xampp\php\php.ini reads:

> include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\ZendFramework-2.1.1\library"

I'm running Windows 7 and my environment variables read:

> C:\xampp\php;C:\ZendFramework-2.1.1\library;C:\ZendFramework-2.1.1\bin

So even though I'm referencing the framework in the php.ini it is still not recognized. Please help

Comment: I've tried this log time and give up, it's too hard do this. I'm using zendframework on my projects but "zf" command line never work's to me. I've to all right like you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a ZF1 vs. ZF2 issue.

The ZF2 command line tool [ZFTool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html) is a distinctly different creature from the ZF1 version.

Looks like you are trying to use a ZF1 tool invocation on a ZF2 installation.